# How do I write a generator to make an alpha string using test.check?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, clojure, test.check

test.check has a built in generator `gen/string-alphanumeric` but it does not have a gen/string-alpha. How do I make a generator that will make strings only composed of letters and no numbers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use gen/char-alpha with gen/fmap to make a string.

```
(gen/fmap clojure.string/join (gen/vector gen/char-alpha))
```

If you need to use this a lot, I recommend binding it. Example:

```
(def gen-string-alpha
  (gen/fmap clojure.string/join (gen/vector gen/char-alpha)))
```

Answer (score 0):

[test.chuck](https://github.com/gfredericks/test.chuck) has a generator, [string-from-regex](https://github.com/gfredericks/test.chuck#string-from-regex) that will prove useful in generating strings that match any desired regular expression.